# AWS Codepipeline builded AWS Lambda, API Gateway returns Malformed Lambda proxy response, 502 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-codepipeline

I prepared a pipeline to create the Lambda & API Gateway. My function was a calculator. 
When I test the Lambda Function separately if gives the correct response but when I invoke my API gateway URL and pass the same JSON it gives error as below.

"

```
Fri Jun 02 09:17:46 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response body before transformations: "Invalid operator entered"
Fri Jun 02 09:17:46 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response headers: {x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, x-amzn-RequestId=57991ca2-4774-11e7-bb26-5f9c6ab6fea6, Connection=keep-alive, Content-Length=26, Date=Fri, 02 Jun 2017 09:17:46 GMT, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-59312d3a-625acffb6cc2497ff543900e;sampled=0, Content-Type=application/json}
Fri Jun 02 09:17:46 UTC 2017 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
Fri Jun 02 09:17:46 UTC 2017 : Method completed with status: 502
```

"

My Lambda function is as below

```
exports.calculator = (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement
    var i1 = event.key1;
    var i2 = event.key2;
    var operation = event.key3;
    switch(operation){
        case '+' : callback(null, i1+i2 );break;
        case '-' : callback(null, i1-i2 );break;
        case '*' : callback(null, i1*i2 );break;
        case '/' : callback(null, i1/i2 );break;
        default:callback(null,"Invalid operator entered");break;
    }
};
```

Any suggestion please

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using the 'proxy' style Lambda integration in API Gateway. You can confirm this in the API Gateway console on the 'Integration Request' page.

In this case, the response generated by the Lambda function must be in this format:

```js
{
  "body": "<payload>",
  "statusCode": <http_status_code>,
  "headers" : {
    <response_headers_map>
  }
}
```

API Gateway will parse this and generate a matching HTTP response for the client.

Comment: I understood the concern and saw on Integration Request page that proxy style has been selected. 

But can you please bit more explain what should i do to resolve it. You have given the response format with explanation but where should I add it. Please help.

Sorry for ignorance. Though I thought it to be putting in Method Response but how?

Comment: I am using Codepipeline to build and deploy.

Comment: I even tried after unselecting Lambda Proxy Integration but ended up with same result.

Comment: can we have a way to define API Gateway with non-proxy Lambda function integration through SAM?

Comment: Your Lambda function code should be creating a response with this structure. You can do whatever processing you want, then you are basically just creating the HTTP response in a JSON format.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Jack. Appreciate you time and help.